# How to get around bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign ()?

Tags: python, materials, scripting

Faced with a problem that causes crash Blender 2.80. 
For automation I created a script from a sequence of actions which works great if I run it in the blender console window, or if i Run Script in a text editor.

But when I run this script through the command line without the graphical shell of the blender - he crashed.

[image]

Еhe exception method was used to find the reason. 
This is the command bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign ()

She is responsible for applying the material to the vertices in Edit Mode.

```
import bpy 

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()    
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')    
bpy.context.object.active_material_index = 1    
bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign()
```

If I exclude bpy.ops.object.material_slot_assign (), the script succeeds, except that the materials are not used.

Who knows how to get around this command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little later, I reported to the developers and they fixed this error. [T70714](https://developer.blender.org/T70714) This question has ceased to be relevant.